# Magento 2 : Triggering Event While Clicking Custom Button

Tags: magento2, event-observer

The custom event should be triggered while clicking the button. I do not have much idea in creating custom events and observers...please help me

Comment: Please don't asking the same question again,Please describe what you want achive and what u have tried so far

Comment: specify your requirement in detail.

Comment: i need to create a custom button in myaccount dashboard..if i am clicking that button an event should be triggered and observer should catch then what ever I am writting in the observer should be executed like showing details or something